# query for substring formation

Tags: sql, database, string

I want to take the `01` part of a string `abcd_01` using SQL. What should be the query for this, where the length before the `_` varies? That is, it may be `abcde_01` or `ab_01`. Basically, I want part after the `_`.

Comment: Is it always the last two characters of the string?

Comment: yes..it is last two characters

Comment: do you want to query all tuples with a value whose some substring is _01?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is one of those examples of how there's similar functionality between SQL and the various extensions, but are just different enough that you can not guarantee portability between all databases.

The [SUBSTRING keyword, using PostgreSQL syntax (no mention of pattern matching) is ANSI-99](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html).  Why this took them so long, I don't know.

The crux of your need is to obtain a substring of the existing column value, so you need to know what the database substring function(s) are called.

### Oracle

---

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcd_01', -2) FROM DUAL
```

Oracle doesn't have a RIGHT function, with is really just a wrapper for the substring function anyway.  But [Oracle's SUBSTR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) does allow you to specify a negative number in order to process the string in reverse (end towards the start).

### SQL Server

---

Two options - [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), and [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcd_01', LEN('abcd_01') - 1, 2)
SELECT RIGHT('abcd_01', 2)
```

For brevity, RIGHT is ideal.  But for portability, SUBSTRING is a better choice...

### MySQL

---

Like SQL Server, three options - [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), and [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_right):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcd_01', LENGTH('abcd_01') - 1, 2)
SELECT SUBSTRING('abcd_01', LENGTH('abcd_01') - 1, 2)
SELECT RIGHT('abcd_01', 2)
```

### PostgreSQL

---

PostgreSQL only has [SUBSTRING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING('abcd_01' FROM LENGTH('abcd_01')-1 for 2)
```

...but it does support limited pattern matching, which you can see is not supported elsewhere.

### SQLite

---

SQLite only supports [SUBSTR](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abcd_01', LENGTH('abcd_01') - 1, 2)
```

### Conclusion

---

Use RIGHT if it's available, while SUBSTR/SUBSTRING would be better if there's a need to port the query to other databases so it's explicit to others what is happening and should be easier to find equivalent functionality.

Comment: Very good answer. Small detail: I think the seperators would be better above the headers. Now the header is to close to the previous answer IMO.

Answer (score 5):

If it's always the last 2 characters then use `RIGHT(MyString, 2)` in most SQL dialects

Comment: RIGHT is only supported by SQL Server and MySQL.  See my answer - there's no silver bullet for consistent substring function name & syntax across databases.

Answer (score 1):

to get 01 from abcd_01 you should write this way (assuming column name is col1)

> SELECT substring(col1,-2) FROM TABLE

this will give you last two chars.

Comment: What DB engines would this work on? Not SQL Server, Oracle uses SUBSTR etc etc

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(names,charindex('_',names)+1,len(names)-charindex('_',names)) from test
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit?