# Full Text Search - Select first lines

Tags: sql, database, full-text-search

I have an application who saves some files in an sql database.
I'm using Full text search for filtering on the documents, now i wonder if it's possible to select the first lines of a document?
So i can make a sort of "google" page for my application

Comment: Database? Code?  Example data & expected output?  Sounds like you want to use the respective substring function for your database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220584/query-for-substring-formation

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL. This will give you first 255 characters from the table which match the columnname againg query.

```
 SELECT SUBSTR(`columnname`, 0, 255) AS blurb FROM `tablename` WHERE MATCH (`columnname`) AGAINST('query');
```

Then, you can disaply the `blurb`  as first few lines of the document.